# How to use the <secret> tag in the remote_servers tag?

Tags: clickhouse

I am modifying the remote_servers tag in config.xml.

Most of the setup was done with the help of stackoverflow.
thank you.

However, when I use the secret tag in the cluster configuration, I get an error.

Below is an example of the settings I have configured.

```
<clusters>
    <secret>same_user</secret>
    <shard>
        <replica>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <default_database>local</default_database>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
    </shard>
    <shard>
        <replica>
            <host>remote1</host>
            <default_database>local</default_database>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
    </shard>
    <shard>
        <replica>
            <host>remote2</host>
            <default_database>local</default_database>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
    </shard>
</clusters>
```

All shard is using the same user and same password.

Also, the user connected as clickhouse-client to execute the query is the same.

But when I execute SELECT COUNT(*) FROM distributedTable in clickhouse-client , an error occurs.
error is
`Code: 101. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Received from remote1:9000. DB::Exception: Hash mismatch.`

This is a query that works fine if i enter the `<user>, <password>` tag without using the secret tag. Is there a cause? I'm using the 20.11.7 version.

Please help if there is a way.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

Must enter the same value for the secret tag of each remote shard config file.

I only put the secret tag on servers using the distributed table engine, and this was a mistake.